# Unable to search sub-string from Ansible variable

Tags: ansible, substring, version, string-matching

I'm trying to create a directory in Ansible if the variable contains the string `7.0.0.GA`

Below is my playbook:

```
- name: Determine the version of Tom
  raw: "cat {{ homefound.path | dirname }}/version.txt | grep -i version"
  register: Tomver

- debug:
    msg: "Tom VERSION IS: {{ Tomver.stdout }}"

- name: Create patch folder /app/Tom_Patches/7.0 on target servers
  file:
    path: /app/Tom_Patches/7.0
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'
  when: Tomver.stdout is match('7.0.0.GA*')
```

In the output I can see that the variable has string `7.0.0.GA` but still `when condition` fails and skips.

Output:

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.9.156.126] => {
    "msg": "Tom VERSION IS: Red Hat Tom Enterprise Application Platform - Version 7.0.0.GA\r\n"
}

TASK [Create patch folder /app/Tom_Patches/7.0 on target servers] ****************************************************************************************************
skipping: [10.9.156.126]
```

I even tried the following condition check but that too fails:

```
  when: Tomver.stdout | join('') | search('7.0.0.GA')
```

I prefer using `raw` module instead of `command` or `shell` module to avoid python dependency.

Can someone please suggest?

Comment: match is expecting a regexp. `'7.0.0.GA*'` means "match '7' followed by any character followed by '0' followed by any character folllowed by '0' followed by any character followed by 'G' followed by 0 or more 'A's". I doubt this is what you are trying to match exactly... Moreover,  it is impossible to help you without knowing what is your input data. Finally, using `raw` is **evil** (unless to install python on the target if not already installed).

Comment: @Zeitounator the text I m trying to match is visible in the output shared user `debug`

Comment: Sorry about the data, I'll be more careful next time when reading. Meanwhile the rest of my comment is still valid.

Comment: Completely agree with your suggestions. Thank you @Zeitounator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a try with the `in`

```
when: "'7.0.0.GA' in res.stdout"
```